# Print readable SQL output in unix terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, unix, terminal

How can I output SQL in Terminal so that is readable even for very long rows?

I have SQL output that is very messy since each row is very long. This makes the table jumbled in my terminal.

I remember a way to output SQL so that it is readable by row. I believe it was done by adding a "\G" at the end of a query but I can't find any documentation on Google.

Answer (score 2):

On linux any output with long lines can be viewed this way:

```
program_that_produces_long_lines | less -S
```

You will have ability to use arrows to see what is outside the screen.